# Windows Server 2008r2 - cannot edit/delete/copy some files which I own and have full access

Tags: windows-server-2008

There's a few folders I need to run a script on.  I have full access to the entire directory and all subdirectories, and when I run the script I get a lot of UnauthorizedAccessException.  Most files I can access as necessary.

When I go to any of the specified files, "effective permissions" shows that I should have full access.  I set myself as owner on all files, as a test, and it still gives me access denied.

The files aren't in use according to Share and Storage Management, however I completely unshared the folder and rebooted to make sure.

When I try to rename the files -- it tells me that I need permission from my own user account to access it.  What is going on?  95% of the files are acting as they should according to permissions.

Comment: Just to make sure, you did check for A/V or similar software, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out people higher in the domain had it blocked by McAfee. Would have expected a different response than "you need permission from Everyone," but McAfee logs show it blocking file access.

Comment: Thanks Nitz -- don't see how to select your comment as the answer but you were right.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, just being the owner is not enough to secure access is basically extends the right to change permissions on a file/directory.   Thus, you can be the owner and still not have access.  You might want to repropogate the ownership change again just in the event something got missed.

I'd try to reset the permissions to FULL CONTROL permissions for yourself and propogate this down the directory tree again.  There might have been something that got missed.

Final thought, have you enabled visibility for system and hidden files (and thus their traversal for permissions changes)?  If these were missed, this might be a cause of this type of problem.

My answer assumes that you are running as either local administrator, have full administrative authority or is a domain administrator.

Comment: Thanks.  Initially, I should have had full control with my domain account being the administrator, however when I ran into files I couldn't access -- I deleted the domain admin groups, set my specific domain account as full control, and as owner, an all files within the directory.  For a vast majority of the files, it works as it is supposed to.  For these few that are giving me trouble, if I go into the security settings for that file, it shows me as owner, me with full access, and effective permissions shows I have full access.

Comment: Stranger, let's say my domain account is "system.administrator" and is the account I'm logged into the server with.  When I try to edit the problematic files in any way -- move, delete, rename -- it says "You require permission from DOMAIN\system.administrator to make changes to this file" -- the same account I'm logged in with.

Comment: I've even set "Everyone" as the owner and full access to the particular file(s) and I get a message that "You require permission from Everyone to make changes to this file."

Comment: Turns out people higher in the domain had it blocked by McAfee.  Would have expected a different response than "you need permission from Everyone," but McAfee logs show it blocking file access.